# Moving XAMPP project to real server

Tags: mysql, apache, iis, xampp, odbc

I'm a college student and an amateur in web development. I've been working on a query system to query some foxpro database tables for this company I am interning in. I was asked to implement my project in their local server (running on Windows Server 2003) and I am not sure where to begin since this will be my first time working with a real server and I have almost zero knowledge about it.

The project was done with PHP, Javascript, mySQL and JQuery and is developed in XAMPP. It will be accessed by everyone on the office intranet. I need to set up  mySQL database for the login as well.

1) Would it be better to do this on IIS or Apache?

2) I am aware that XAMPP is Apache, but if I implement my project on IIS, will there be any difference or will I need to change my codes?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *Dont trouble trouble, till trouble troubles you..* Generally there shouldn't be any issues, as long as the IIS server has all you need to run the PHP files E.G:PHP ;p your need to do an alternative for any .htaccess files you have, but you wont know that till you get your files on the server. Do a `phpinfo()` on both servers and compare the results. Good luck

Comment: You mentioned querying FoxPro tables. But you say you're going to deploy on MySQL. Can you explain the RDMS part of your project a little more clearly?

Comment: @LozCherone Thank you for your response, I will post back again once the implementation period starts next week. Crossing my fingers here!

Comment: @OllieJones The FoxPro tables (that came from another software) is extracted and left in a folder in their DBF formats. I installed a foxpro ODBC driver on my machine and set up the DSN to do the querying. But I'm storing my login details (accounts, password, acess level) for the system in a mySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is governed by

1. the tech your project uses.
2. your need to coexist with the other services on that company W2003 server.

If your project happens to be the first web app to be served from that server, just set up XAMPP, move your files and database to the server, and be done with it.

But it's unlikely.  You need to talk to whomever set up the last web app on that server. It's possible to set up a server so some web pages are served by IIS and others by Apache, but then those pages need different port numbers. That will make things more confusing and less convenient for your users.

php/MySQL/odbc works fine on IIS if that's what you need to use. You may have to monkey around with protections and so forth to get it tweaked out. But it will perform just fine.

The take-home lesson for you as you develop this small scale web app is to build things like that to fit the intended production deployment environment. XAMPP is a popular and successful development setup PRECISELY BECAUSE there are approximately Avogadro's Number of $4-per-month Linux-Apache-MySQL-php hosting services in the world that are entirely compatible with it.  But that's not your deployment target this time.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response, sir. Actually this will be the first web app to be served from that server, hehe. 

Am I correct in understanding that I have the option of installing XAMPP on that server and use it to host my web app? I have read somewhere before that it is not a good practice to use XAMPP due to security issues.

Also, do you know if the FTP of XAMPP functions well in real environment? We would like to do scheduled automatic database tables (the foxpro) uploads.

Again, thanks for your time. I would love to upvote but unfortunately my reputation is too low.